# Android Wheel concept

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android.  I have an Activity where I have a couple of buttons.  Among them when I click on one button, I want to get dropdown like iPhone default picker.

To achieve that, I am using Android wheel concept.  I have implemented like this, when I click on the button, it is calling another activity where my required custom layout is shown. Problem is custom layout should come from bottom of the screen in the same activity where the button I am clicking exists.

I have attached a screenshot. I want to achieve as shown in the screenshot (missing).

Please help me providing the required solution. Pardon me if there any mistakes in my question. This is the first time to ask a question.

Comment: Please add your screenshot, I don't see any.

Answer (score 0):

Since the lack of a screenshot that helps to understand your issue, this is more some kind of guess: Are you known to the concept of [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) in Android? They provide a dropdown mechanism and are easily implemented.